# Repeater not showing items from SQL Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I need to use a Repeater to display data from an SQL Data Source object, but it's not working. I tried the same with GridView and it worked fine, so everything is working except for the Repeater thing.

The result I get is a bunch of "System.Data.DataRowView System.Data.DataRowView..."

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    repeater.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    repeater.DataBind();


}
```

ASP:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItem %>

     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How and where is SqlDataSource1 defined?

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:lebesConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CodArtifact], [CodFlowElement], [CodFlow] FROM [wfARTIFACT]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: It's supposed to be working, I used it to display data wit a GridView and it worked correctly, I figure the problem lies on the Repeater controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in your itemtemplate tag  with Eval("YourColumnName") or Databinder.Eval().

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("CodFlowElement")%>

</ItemTemplate>
```

or you can use like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CodFlowElement")%>

</ItemTemplate>
```